# Connectedness of a set of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Is the  graph of {$xy=1$} in $\mathbb C^2$ connected?

I know $xy=1$ is disconnected in $\mathbb R^2$ by drawing its graph.But how to approach in $C^2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is connected.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more

Comment: Move $x$ from its original location to $1$ while keeping $xy=1$.